# Create a public UI for my custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to SF development as such would appreciate any pointers on this.

I have a custom object which I would like to expose it to the world and everyone can access the add/edit data without requiring authentication.

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites

Have a look at above document.Force.com offers component called sites and you can achieve your requirement using sites which require no authentication.

you can build your own visualforce and expose for public on sites.